# Add description to a Servant OpenAPI specification

Tags: haskell, openapi, haskell-lens, servant

Want to add description to OpenAPI schemas, paths, parameters... to all OpenAPI elements where a description child element is allowed.

```hs
module Spec.User where

import           Control.Lens
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.OpenApi
import           Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import           GHC.Generics
import           Servant

data User =
    User
        { name :: String
        , age :: Int
        }
    deriving (Show, Generic, Typeable)

instance ToJSON User

instance ToSchema User where
    declareNamedSchema proxy = do
        userSchema <- genericDeclareNamedSchema defaultSchemaOptions proxy
        return $ userSchema
            & schema . description ?~ descSchema
            & schema . properties . ix "name" . mapped . description ?~ descName
            & schema . properties . ix "age" . mapped . description ?~ descAge
      where
        descSchema = "This is the description of 'User' schema"
        descName = "This is the description of 'User.name'"
        descAge = "This is the description of 'User.age'"


newtype UserId =
    UserId Integer
    deriving (Show, Generic, Typeable, ToJSON)

instance ToSchema UserId

instance ToParamSchema UserId

type GetUsers = Get '[JSON] [User]
type GetUser  = Capture "user_id" UserId :> Get '[JSON] User
type PostUser = ReqBody '[JSON] User :> Post '[JSON] UserId

-- FIXME Add description per path, parameter, and response

type UserAPI  = GetUsers :<|> GetUser :<|> PostUser
```

Documentation of a schema is kind of OK but error prune. For example, misspelling 'name' or 'age' leads to no warning or error.

But, what currently concerns me more is how to "easily" and "safely" add **description**s to path specifications? E.G.

```
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      DESCRIPTION: |
        bla blub ...
      operationId: findUsers
      parameters:
        - name: tags
          in: query
          DESCRIPTION: foo bar ...
          required: false
          style: form
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
        - name: limit
          in: query
          DESCRIPTION: baz boo ...
          required: false
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
      responses: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [servant-openapi3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-openapi3) to auto-generate OpenAPI from Servant. You can then use field lenses to add extra annotation such as descriptions, see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-openapi3-2.0.1.1/docs/Servant-OpenApi.html#g:3).

Comment: I'm already using servant-openapi3. The problem is not how to generate but how to add content.

Comment: I don't see you have `Servant.OpenAPI` imported. Is the doc link I posted not what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, I haven't posted `BSL8.putStrLn $ encode $ toOpenApi (Proxy :: Proxy UserAPI)` but the basis for it. Let me put it another way. Can you code the above OpenAPI snippet (`/users: ...`) in Servant-OpenAPI3 including all descriptions?